# Split column preserving values

Tags: openrefine

I have a column of words followed by numbers, like this:

[image]

I want to split it into two columns, putting the text to the left of the digits in the first column, and the digits and any text that follow into the second column.

I suspect I'll have to add a column based on this column, containing the digits and everything after. Then I'll have to delete the digits and everything after from the previous column.

I'm not great at GREL, and the examples I've found don't work. Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways. If you don't like GREL but you know some regular expressions, you can use "Edit column" -> Split into several columns "and use as separator this regex :

```
\s(?=\d)
```

It means "[any space that is before a number](https://regex101.com/r/fSMeu8/7)".

[image]

(Don't forget to check the box "regular expression".)

If any of your values contain multiple numbers (eg, "text 123 newtext 345 sometext"), specify "split into 2 columns at most".